# C++ substring searching - JUMPING INTO C++

Tags: c++

I'm reading "Jumping Into C++" by Alex Allain. I'm at a chapter on strings and searching strings, and I don't really understand this for-loop. Someone please explain to me how this works. Thanks.

```
for ( i = input.find( "cat", 0 ); i != string::npos; i = input.find( "cat", i ) )
{
    cat_appearances++;
    i++; // Move past the last discovered instance to avoid
    // finding same string again
}
    cout << "The word cat appears " << cat_appearances << " in the string
    " << '"' << input << '"';
}
```

Comment: Please read the reference yourself [std::basic_string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: What do you not understand? Did you read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos

Answer (score 2):

It has the same structure as every `for` loop:

```
for (initialise once; compare before each iteration; post iteration)
```

But normally you'd see something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

That is: initialise `i = 0` once, then check if `i < 5` before each iteration of the loop, then perform `i++` after.

Yours instead initialises `i` to the result of `find("cat", 0)`: that is, it finds the first occurrence of "cat" in the string `input`.

Before each loop, it checks that `i != std::string::npos`; that is, it checks to make sure we actually found an occurrence of "cat" in `input`, since `find` will return `std::string::npos` if no occurrence is found.

At the end of each loop, it will then `i = input.find("cat", i)`, which will search again for an occurrence of "cat" starting from our current position.

The actual loop itself just counts occurrences.

Comment: why was this downvoted? this is a very nice explanation.

Comment: @skeller idk? because... reasons?

Comment: Because the question demonstrates zero effort of any kind?